# read_csv for text file with values separated by a certain amount of spaces or less

Tags: python, pandas

Text file I am trying to read from
[image]

How can I use whitespace as a delimiter and still be able to read empty space as NaN values? I tried using the code below to separate all content by 7 spaces or less. Any event where a character is separated from another by more than 7 white spaces means that an empty value must lie in between.

```
import pandas
df = pandas.read_csv('/Users/mthomas/Desktop/03 (1).TXT', sep='\s|\s\s|\s\s\s|\s\s\s\s|\s\s\s\s\s|\s\s\s\s\s\s|\s\s\s\s\s\s\s|\n')
```

I got the result below which is obviously not what I wanted.

[image]

Comment: you should use delim_whitespace=True in your read_csv instead of this long string of sep. But I think it won't help with NaNs, it will leave them at the end...

Comment: upload the data so that we can help

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas
df = pandas.read_csv('/Users/mthomas/Documents/python_projects/Vinyl Wrap/Data Logger 3', sep="\s{1,7]")
```

this worked